# Jquery popping 2 many alerts and wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

G´Evening

I want JQuery to pop up an alert, when I click on the Image and then display the x and y coordinates of the Position of the cursor in the Image.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(300)
            $('#blah').mouseenter(function (e) {
                $(this).click(function (e) {
                    alert(e.pageX + ' , ' + e.pageY);
                })
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <div id="divfuerimage" height="300px" width="300px" >
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="cursor: pointer"/>
    </div>
```

Right now I randomly get 1-5 Alerts when I click once and the X and Y coordinates are from the whole page, but I want the coordinates in the Image only.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: That is because the click event is getting bound everytime you enter `#blah` with the mouse, causing duplicate events.

Comment: @anton how can i fix this then?

Comment: bind the click event in document.ready `$(document).ready(function(){/*Click event*/ /*Functions*/ });` outside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the click event is getting bound everytime you enter `#blah` with the mouse, causing duplicate events.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).width(300).height(300)
            $('#blah').mouseenter(function (e) { /*code for mouseenter*/ });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#blah').on('click', function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
            pageX = e.pageX,
            pageY = e.pageY;
        var imgX = pageX-offset.left,
            imgY = pageY-offset.top;
        alert(imgX + ' , ' + imgY);
    });
});
```

Comment: with the code you gave me, my image is not getting displayed anymore

Comment: #blah will trigger an alert before readURL is executed with this solution.

Comment: @anton thanks it´s working now. How can i solve my 2nd Problem that i get the coordinates of the whole page? (i want the ones from the image only)

Comment: @anton no, this gives me the position of the image. I mean i want the position of the cursor in the image

Comment: @FelixLahmer I've updated the answer. example of cursor in the image position here http://jsfiddle.net/tuppp1nu/1/

Comment: internet explorer is printing the y coordinate as a 20 digit decimal, do u have a quick hint mbe?

Comment: @FelixLahmer like 2.12314923? if so `parseInt(imgY);`

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is for readURL to create an `<img>` element when it successfully reads a file.

Your coordinate issue is solved by using this.position()

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            if ($('#blah')) {
                $('#blah').remove();
            }
            $('<img id="blah" />')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(300)
                .click(function (e) {
                    window.alert($(this).position().top + ' , ' + $(this).position().left);
                }).appendTo($('#divfuerimage'));
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<div id="divfuerimage" height="300px" width="300px" >
</div>
```

Comment: what is the advantage of this technique? usually i prefer seeing all my elements in the html

Comment: sorry but im not getting any alert using your alert(this.position().x + ' , ' + this.position().Y);

Comment: The advantage is that you're not creating an invalid image element tht points to nothing, and you're only creating / destroying events as you need them.  Do me a favor and try clicking the empty image  in anton's solution above.  It will trigger an alert despite the fact that the image is not supposed to be loaded yet.

Comment: ah okay, i understand that. I will modify it thank you

Comment: but the image doesnt get displayed somehow

Comment: Well, 5 minutes of debugging, and I got it to work... I had an extra jQuery close, and some misuse of $(this).position()... this will work for you now.

Comment: thanks for your help, I did not take your answer because the coordination calculation (where is my cursor in the picture), is not working in your example. But i really appreciate your hint with the invalid image element and mixed your codes and its running fluently now. I upvoted you :)